# Google API Picker missing folders

Tags: javascript, angularjs, permissions, google-picker

I have a picker to select folders, it has been working smoothly but lately I'm unable to see some folders, but only on a very specific folder.
e.g. I used to view 6 different folders, but suddenly I was only able to see 3. After searching I've found that all folders share the same permissions, and no one has changed anything on the drive, yet I'm still unable to view all my folders. The odd thing is that when viewing the drive through the browser I'm able to see all the files and folders (using the same account), the other odd thing is that this only seems to happen on a single folder, not on the entire drive.

I'm almost completely sure that the problem is drive permissions, but can't seem to fix them or change them to view all my folders.

This is my code for creating the picker

```
function createFolderPicker(parentId) {
  parentId = parentId || 'root';
  if (pickerApiLoaded && $window.localStorage.googleToken) {
    var view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS);
    view.setParent(parentId);
    view.setSelectFolderEnabled(true);
    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
      addView(view).
      setOAuthToken($window.localStorage.googleToken).
      setSelectableMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder').
      setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
      setCallback(pickerFolderCallback).
      build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are these folders displayed on the same hierarchy? Or is it that some folders are contained inside. Also, Are you the owner of the folders or someone has  administrative access to them also?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same hierarchy, I am not the owner of the folders, but do belong on a group that has access to them. Also I have tried with the administrative account (the one that owns them) and still see the same issue.